# Delayed_job not working in production PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "delayed_jobs" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have delayed_job running on my development setup and runs fine, when I push to the staging/production server I get the following error whenever a job is added to the queue;

```
/home/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `async_exec': PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "delayed_jobs" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"delayed_jobs"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"delayed_jobs"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

this is irrelavent of what job is added but everything works as expected in development.

The table is migrated and exists on the staging server;

== 20141009165225 CreateDelayedJobs: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:delayed_jobs, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0158s
-- add_index(:delayed_jobs, [:priority, :run_at], {:name=>"delayed_jobs_priority"})
   -> 0.0070s
== 20141009165225 CreateDelayedJobs: migrated (0.0236s) =======================

I have dropped and recreated the database but have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: That SQL is what ActiveRecord uses to figure out a table's structure. Are you sure the table exists? Where "sure" means that you've connected to PostgreSQL through `psql` and checked that the table really is there.

Comment: I've connected through psql and the table exists

Comment: Is staging connecting to the right database?

Comment: yeah, figured out the problem was with using whenever which was always using the production environment to call delayed_job

Comment: If you have indeed solved the problem as a classic environment mixup, could you delete the question?